why my bash PS1 prompt writing over same line
export PS1="\e[32;40m\]\$?\[\e[35;40m\]\$(date +%d%H%M)\[\e[36;40m\]\W>\[\e[38;5;113;40m\]"


not return at the end of line and same line...


fyi for future questions: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

 export PS1="\[\e[32;40m\]\$?\[\e[35;40m\]\$(date +%d%H%M)\[\e[36;40m\]\W>\[\e[38;5;113;40m\]"

missing [ at the begining of ps1
